# Javascript alert when space or no entered value

Tags: javascript, html

I need to write a regular expression for form validation that allows spaces within a string, but doesn't allow only white space.Example, if the user just enter spaces, it should trigger javascript alert

I tried this but this not work

```
<script>

if (document.getElementsByClassName('notes') == " ") {
    alert("Notes should not begin with space");
}
```

}

html

```
 <textarea name="notes" class="form-control" class="notes"></textarea>
```

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName('notes')` ==> `document.getElementsByClassName('notes')[0].value` Why don't you trim spaces using `.trim()`

Comment: I need to throw an alert if field has no value or just spaces entered by the user before submit

Answer (score 1):

`if (document.getElementsByClassName('notes') == " ")`

`getElementsByClassName()` returns  a collection of nodes not value of node , use `[]` and `value` property along with `trim()` .

```
if(document.getElementsByClassName('notes')[0].value.trim() === "")
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to  get the `value` of `input`like:

```
if (document.getElementsByClassName('notes')[0].value == "") {
        alert("Notes should not begin with space");
    }
```

Ps. The `getElementsByClassName` will return a list of elements. So,when compared with `" "` will always return `false`.

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing the array of elements that document.getElementsByClassName returns to " ", which will obviously be false, you want to compare the value of the element.

```
if (document.getElementsByClassName('notes')[0].value[0] == " ") {
    alert("Notes should not begin with space");
}
```

In this example, the `.value` returns the value of the textarea, and `.value[0]` means the first char of the value

Answer (score 1):

Please check your HTML. There are two class attributes:

```
<textarea name="notes" class="form-control" class="notes"></textarea>
```

Combine them first :

```
<textarea name="notes" class="form-control notes"></textarea>
```

Now the selector

```
document.getElementsByClassName('notes')[0]
```

should give you the target element.

Comment: This will give me the alert but right after the form is submitted.Any idea how to pop up the alert and prevent submit?

Comment: What do you mean by "Right after the form is submitted ?". You have not mentioned anything about form submission in your question !

Answer (score 0):

Ok I got it. All answers above are correct, but I have to add "onclick" event on submit

```
 <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-default" value="submit" onclick="return showAlert()">
```

js

```
 <script>
function showAlert(){
    if (document.getElementsByClassName('notes')[0].value[0] == " ") {
    alert("Notes should not begin with space");
    return false;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this it is working fine :**

**HTML :**

```
<textarea name="notes" class="form-control notes"></textarea>
```

**Script :**

```
$('textarea').on('keyup', function(){
if (document.getElementsByClassName('notes')[0].value[0] == " ") {
    alert("Notes should not begin with space");
}
});
```

Demo : https://jsfiddle.net/fer49eby/